# NSKeyedArchiver not persisting data Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nskeyedarchiver

I have a an app in production I'm trying to convert from Swift 2.2 to Swift 3. I have tried the Swift 3 code in both XCode 8.1 and XCode 8.2.

The following Swift 2 code works perfectly:

```
func saveItemsToCache() {
    NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(items, toFile: itemsCachePath)
}

func loadItemsFromCache() {
    if let cachedItems = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(itemsCachePath) as? [TruckItem] {
        items = cachedItems
    }
}

var itemsCachePath: String {
    let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    let fileURL = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Trucks.dat")
    return fileURL.path!
}
```

But the data isn't being persisted when I use the same code converted for Swift 3:

```
func saveItemsToCache() {
    print("SAVED TRUCKS:", items)
    NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(items, toFile: itemsCachePath)
}

func loadItemsFromCache() {
    if let cachedItems = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: itemsCachePath) as? [TruckItem] {
        items = cachedItems
        print("LOADED TRUCKS:", items)
    }
}

var itemsCachePath: String {
    let documentsURL = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("Trucks.dat")
    return fileURL.path
}
```

Example console output:

```
SAVED TRUCKS: [<TruckTelematics.TruckItem: 0xc852380>, <TruckTelematics.TruckItem: 0x9b23ba0>]

LOADED TRUCKS: []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently discovered that the issue wasn't with NSKeyedArchiver at all, but instead with the `convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` method in my NSObject subclass `TruckItem`.

In Swift 2.2, you would decode different object properties like this:

```
let IMEI = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: CodingKeys.IMEI) as! String
let active = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: CodingKeys.active) as! Bool
let daysInactive = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: CodingKeys.daysInactive) as! Int
```

In Swift 3, instead of using `decodeObject()` for all property types, it appears there are now some new functions to be aware of. Here are the same object properties decoded in Swift 3:

```
let IMEI = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: CodingKeys.IMEI) as! String
let active = aDecoder.decodeBool(forKey: CodingKeys.active)
let daysInactive = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: CodingKeys.daysInactive)
```

It took quite some time for me to discover this, hopefully this answer saves other users from similar frustration.